# Regex enclosed with () Issue

Tags: regex, regex-group, capturing-group

I'm having a regular expression

```
(\\w+[ ]*|-\\w+[ ]*)(!=|<=|>=|=|<|>| not in | in | not like | like )(.*)
```

This has 3 sections sepearted by comma.

When I try to match this against something like

```
product(getProduct_abc) in (Xyz)
```

It's not matching the regex.

But when I try to match

```
100=product(getProduct_abc) in (Xyz)
```

it matches Perfectly.

What's wrong with the regex?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do too much in one regex. Break it down and parse the string properly.

Comment: Anon, this is the Regular Expression given by our business users to validate with. We cannot change it. Please let me know what's the better way to understand & parse it clearly. Any help is much appreicated.

Comment: @Anon: The regular expression, as it stands independently, is fine. We cannot judge if it is trying to do too much or too little because we don't know Preethi's requirements. A more complex parser may be over-complex for his needs--or he may well need one. We just don't know enough about his task.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong, per se, with the regular expression. It just does not match the specified string.

You need to find yourself a good reference on regular expressions and learn the basics. One is http://www.regular-expressions.info/ . That one may or may not be a good reference to you as a beginner. (I am using his RegexBuddy tool to test your regular expression.)

Here is a rough breakdown of the expression:

- There are three capturing groups, each surrounded by their own pair of parentheses. (Note that parentheses, along with many other characters, have a special meaning in regular expressions, so to match a parenthesis of either direction you need to escape it. The given regular expression does not do this.)
- In the first capturing group there are two possible choices for a match. They are:

  - One or more "word" characters followed by zero or more spaces, or
  - A dash, followed by one or more "word" characters followed by zero or more spaces
- In the second capturing group, there are 10 possible matches: the listed operator symbols (without surrounding spaces), or the listed textual operators (with surrounding spaces)
- In the third capturing group, zero or more of any character at all will match.

The string 'product(getProduct_abc) in (Xyz)' fails to match because prior to the '`in`' operator there are more than just "word" characters. The parentheses are not considered "word" characters, and therefore cause the match to fail.

The second string ('100=product(getProduct_abc) in (Xyz)') matches because it uses the equals ('=') as the matched operator for the second capturing group, '100' is a string of all "word" characters, and everything after the '=' matches the "any character" part, so the match succeeds. Note that depending on how the end-of-string is handled, some languages might not match even that string if it is at the very end of the string.

If the first string is *supposed* to match, then you need to check with your business users. Maybe they are beginners with regular expressions too, and gave you one that doesn't work. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see:

```
'100=product(getProduct_abc) in (Xyz)'  
Group1 match = '100'  
Group2 match = '='  
Group3 match = 'product(getProduct_abc) in (Xyz)'  

'product(getProduct_abc) in (Xyz)'  
        ^  
    Fails here on Group1 match because parenthesis are not included in this group
```

---

You can fix the situation by forcing the last occurance of group 1,2,3 match in the string.
Fixing/Rewriting the equavalent Group1 match and separating the groups, they can be re-combined to force the last match possible.

```
rxP1 = '(?:-?[\w()]+\ *)';
rxP2 = '(?:!=|<=|>=|=|<|>| not in | in | not like | like )';
rxP3 = '(?:.*?)';

rxAll = /(?:$rxP1$rxP2$rxP3)*($rxP1)($rxP2)($rxP3)$/;
```

In Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @samples = (
 'product(getProduct_abc) in (Xyz1)',
 '100=product(getProduct_abc) in (Xyz2)',
 '100 like = != not like >product(getProduct_abc) in (Xyz3)',
);

my $rxP1 = '(?:-?[\w()]+\ *)';
my $rxP2 = '(?:!=|<=|>=|=|<|>| not in | in | not like | like )';
my $rxP3 = '(?:.*?)';

for (@samples)
{
    if ( /(?:$rxP1$rxP2$rxP3)*($rxP1)($rxP2)($rxP3)$/ ) {
        print "\n1 = '$1'\n";
        print "2 = '$2'\n";
        print "3 = '$3'\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 = 'product(getProduct_abc)'
2 = ' in '
3 = '(Xyz1)'

1 = 'product(getProduct_abc)'
2 = ' in '
3 = '(Xyz2)'

1 = 'product(getProduct_abc)'
2 = ' in '
3 = '(Xyz3)'
```